# What's the proper place to put app configurations for gmail addon?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

For a gmail add-on we are developing we need to be able to put different API url's for development vs. production, along with some other configurations. What would be the proper place to put these configurations and how to read them? I saw we can add script properties from Project Properties window and i am guessing we can read them using [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties), but the problem is how can we have different configurations based on environment.

Any ideas?

Comment: what kind of environment? can you give sample code of what you tried to do?

Comment: @e__n i don't have a sample code for this, as i do not know where to put the configurations. Right now i am just hard coding stuff (ex: authorization URL) in my code. I am just trying to find a place where to keep the app configuration, so i can change the them when i want to go live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, store them in the Properties Service, specifically, the Script Properties. You can still access them and modify them after you publish.

Comment: I didn't know they can be updated after publish. I'll use the Script Properties, thanks.